# postgresql: Group select by year and month from epoch time

Tags: postgresql

I need to get an output from the postgresql db as follows:

2016
    Nov
    Dec
  2017
    Jan
    Feb
    Mar

I've been googling, testing, playing but hasn't come close.
So I tuen to you guys that will show me what nord I am!
I do know how to do this in mysql but postgres no.

Oh yeah it is Postgres 9.6.

Comment: Don't you think its too difficult to understand `2016 Nov Dec 2017 Jan Feb Mar` and make assumptions on `Group select by year and month from epoch time`

Comment: Do you mean that years and months should be in same column ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It is very hard for other people to understand your question ? Try to add sample data and output which you want.

Comment: My example got screwed. I'd like to group the months by its year.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but may be you need this ?

```
with your_table(dt) as(
    select '2016-11-01'::date union all
    select '2016-11-02'::date union all
    select '2016-12-01'::date union all
    select '2017-01-01'::date union all
    select '2017-02-01'::date union all
    select '2017-02-02'::date union all
    select '2017-03-01'::date union all
    select '2017-10-01'::date union all
    select '2017-11-01'::date union all
    select '2018-02-01'::date  
)

-- Above is just table simulation, actual query is below:

select case when month_name is null then y::text else month_name end from (
    select extract(year from dt) as y, 0 as month_number, null as month_name   from your_table group by extract(year from dt)
    union all
    select extract(year from dt), extract(month from dt) as month_number, '--'||to_char(min(dt), 'Mon') as month_name from your_table
    group by extract(year from dt), extract(month from dt)
) t
order by y, month_number
```

Comment: But in my database there is not dt column. id, dw, up, lt, uxts. uxts is an epoch time column.

Comment: @swe_mattias - In uxts column do you have data like this: `1494800648` ?

Comment: I know I am unclear with my question I am bit to unaccustomed with postgresql so I don't really know how I should express my problems.

Comment: @swe_mattias - If you edit your question, post sample data from your table and then expected output, may be it will more clear then.

Comment: After days of googling I found that to_timestamp works in postgresql. That solves part of my problem. Either that cumbersome way to group in python or directly in sql.

Comment: After reading through your comments it gave me more google options and after some thought I cam up with this with is close to what I what.

select date_part('month',to_timestamp(uxts)) as mon,
 extract('year' from to_timestamp(uxts)) as yyyy
from speed
group by 1, 2